# How to display menu bar in Macbook pro 14 inch in full screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, menu-bar

The question is in the title : How to display the menu bar in a Macbook Pro 14' in full screen apps ?

The menu stays accessible, but it's not visible :

[image]

Thanks everyone for your answers !

Comment: What's the point of fullscreen if you always show the menu bar? That's just 'maximised'… which, imo, is far more useful than fullscreen anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're right, but in fullscreen with my Macbook Air 13' I can display the menu bar by hovering the top of the screen (See the image here : https://ibb.co/nzT5PyC). This is not possible with the new Macbook Pro 14' ...

Comment: Ah, OK. That wasn't obvious from your question. Is it only Chrome that displays this behaviour, or all apps?

Comment: Sorry! I have this problem with all apps, even Finder ...

Comment: Have you updated the OS as far as you can?[12.1 I think is latest]  Monterey was very buggy at initial release. [So much so I won't go anywhere near it yet;)

Comment: Done and the menu bar is here now ! You can write the answer and I will validate it, thanks !

Comment: Go for it! I don't need the points. Happy New Year.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin, happy new year too ! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, according to the Tetsujin answer in my question, **you need to upgrade MacOS to, at least, the 12.1 version** to see the menu bar in full screen.

Now, it works like a charm !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).